# Cardinality of Solutions to an Inequality

Tags: probability, combinatorics, inequality, special-functions

Show that the number of solutions in nonneg. int. of the ineq.
$$x_1+x_2+\cdots +x_n\leq M,$$
where $M$ is a nonneg. int., is $C(M+n,n)$.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: The number of solutions in non-negative integers to

$$x_1+x_2+\ldots+x_n\le M$$

is the same as the number of solutions in non-negative integers to

$$x_1+x_2+\ldots+x_n+x_{n+1}=M\;,$$

which is a standard [stars-and-bars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28probability%29) problem.

Comment: But that gives $\begin{pmatrix}n+M\\M\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: @Gabriel: Which is equal to $\binom{n+M}n$. Remember the symmetry property of binomial coefficients: $\binom{n}k=\binom{n}{n-k}$.